# Find the first line in a multi-line import from statement with Python's AST

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm currently trying to find all `ast.Import` and `ast.ImportFrom` nodes in a Python file. However, in a multi-line import statement, like

```
from foo import (
bar,
baz,
coo
)
```

the lineno mentioned for each submodule (`bar`, `baz`, and `coo`) are all at the line where they are mentioned, not the original `from foo import` line. How can I get just the line where the import statement begins (for single line imports, it would just be the same).

Alternatively, is there a way to get all imports in a scope, iteratively (going through all the scopes in the script)?

**Update:** Apparently, `ast.walk` doesn't return a node for each line, like I thought. It was actually because I made a different tuple for every `node.names`. Fixing it to only return the first name (and use node.lineno) works out great. However @rici's answer is still good, so I'll leave this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the `lineno` attribute of the `ast.ImportFrom` node, which is the line number of the start of the statement. (There's also an `end_lineno` attribute, probably less useful for this case.)

Here's a small example:

```py
import ast
sample = '''
# This is line 1
#
# This is line 3
#
# The next line is line 6
from foo import (
   bar,
   baz,
   coo
)
import pkg.mod, other_mod
'''.strip()
class myWalker(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Import(self, node):
        print(f"""Line {node.lineno} imports modules {
                  ', '.join(alias.name for alias in node.names)
               }""")
    def visit_ImportFrom(self, node):
        print(f"""Line {node.lineno} imports from module {node.module} the names {
                  ', '.join(alias.name for alias in node.names)
               }""")

myWalker().visit(ast.parse(sample, filename='<test>', mode='exec'))
```

Output:

```py
Line 6 imports from module foo the names bar, baz, coo
Line 11 imports modules pkg.mod, other_mod
```

To get the import names by scope, I think you'd have to walk the syntax tree, noting function definitions. (Other scopes, such as lambdas and comprehensions, don't matter here because they only allow expressions, not statements. But if you want to do it right, you'll need to also keep track of names declared `global` or `nonlocal`, because a function could use one of those declarations to inject an imported name into a different scope.)

Comment: Please check the question again. I made a mistake in the formatting.

Comment: @DrownedSuccess: That doesn't change my answer at all. I'll add a small example to demonstrate feasibility.

Comment: But what about the fact that there will be multiple ImportFrom nodes for each of the submodules?

Comment: @DrownedSuccess: you see my code and you see what happens when it runs. What makes you think there are multiple importFrom  nodes?

Comment: If I use `ast.walk`, I get multiple `ImportFrom` nodes for each line in a multi-line import from statement (hence my question). Are you saying `ast.NodeVisitor` does not have this "problem", but joins all the lines into one node?

Comment: @DrownedSuccess: my answer contains a complete Python program which you can copy into a file and run. You can also use ast.dump to look at the AST; you will not see multiple importFrom nodes. If you have an issue with some code you wrote, SO guidelines say that you must provide the code (see [mre]). If you edit that into your question, I'll look at it. But it seems to me that this answer does show how to "just get the line where the import statement begins." If it doesn't work for you, please let me know (include your Python version number).

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @DrownedSuccess: For what it's worth, `ast.walk` does not return multiple `ImportFrom` nodes for your sample code. It returns one `ImportFrom` node and multiple `alias` nodes, and you can get the starting line number from the `ImportFrom` node, as I have been saying from the start. And you can also get the list of imported aliases directly from the `ImportFrom` object (in its `names` attribute). On the whole, subclassing `ast.NodeVisitor` as in this answer is much simpler. `ast.walk` is, in my experience, not generally very useful.

Comment: Huh, you're right --- I was convinced that it showed multiple nodes. Guess I was wrong and this question was for naught (learned something new though).

Comment: Oh, I figured out why I kept making the mistake --- I made a separate tuple for every submodule! Mea culpa.